# Unable to import FormModule into Angular4 project, ng.forms.FormModule is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

I am using vanilla javascript with Angular 4 (it is a requirement, please do not say 'use typescript'), and I am looking to use the FormModule. ng.forms is available just fine but ng.forms.FormModule does not exist.

How to get around this / why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Newbie here but what I have seen is that NgForm and FormsModule both fall under '@angular/forms' here are the imports Angular 4.
[FormsModule](https://v4.angular.io/api/forms/FormsModule)
[NgForm](http://import%20%7B%20NgForm%20%7D%20from%20'@angular/forms';)